# Pydantic Models inside a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, pydantic

Cannot insert a pydantic model into a pandas DataFrame.

I cannot figure out what about classes that inherit from pydantic's BaseModel means that they cannot be inserted into a DataFrame whereas other classes can.

For example:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    name: str

df = pd.DataFrame()
inst = Test(name='Brian')
df.at[0, 'test'] = inst

print(df)
```

will output

```
                 test
0  Test(name='Brian')
```

(the above also works for non dataclasses as well)

whereas for a pydantic model

```
class Test(BaseModel):
    name: str
```

pandas seems to interpret the model as `list_like`
and fails with error:

> TypeError: object of type 'Test' has no len()

This goes for pandas insert, loc, iloc, at, iat

Whilst its not the most obvious use case for a DataFrame I am working with a codebase that expects to be able to insert and retrieve classes as objects from dataframe fields and I am currently attempting to change some classes to use Pydantic.

Why does pandas assume pydantic models are list_like and is there a way around this?

---

UPDATE:
I found a way to make this work although it is not ideal...

Pandas uses a method `is_list_like` - one can find it in pandas._libs.lib.pyx but as it is written Pyrex it is hard to tell why a dataclass is not list_like and a pydantic class is, someone may be able to enlighten me on that one.

Anyway to get around this I noticed pandas checks the value's 'ndim' attribute > 0 with a default of 1. If this condition fails then the value is set using the `_setitem_single_column` method in the pandas `_iLocIndexer` class.

Therefore setting ndim=0 on the pydantic class allows for it to be set as a field value in a pandas df.

```
class Test(BaseModel):
    name: str
    ndim = 0
```

Comment: Have you looking into [`Pydantic - pandera`](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pydantic_integration.html) Might solve your problem?